# Multiple buttons that change the text of a Meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm just starting out with MeteorJS

If I have a series of buttons, is there a way of changing the body text of a page depending on which button I click?

If I have a button called "Hello", I would like the body text to change to "Hello".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Using a `Session` variable.**

HTML

```
<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
  <p>{{text}}</p>
  {{> button}}
</template>

<template name="button">
  <button type="button">Hello</button>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.main.onCreated(function(){
  Session.set("text", "Default");
});

Template.main.helpers({
  text: function(){
    return Session.get("text");
  }
});

Template.button.events({
  "click button": function(event, template){
    var buttonText = template.$("button").text();
    Session.set("text", buttonText);
  }
});
```

**Using a `ReactiveVar` to avoid globals and provide better component encapsulation.**

HTML is the same.

JS

```
Template.main.onCreated(function(){
  this.text = new ReactiveVar("Default");
});

Template.main.helpers({
  text: function(){
    return Template.instance().text.get();
  }
});

Template.button.events({
  "click button": function(event, template){
    var buttonText = template.$("button").text();
    // search for a field named text in the closest parent template (main)
    template.get("text").set(buttonText);
  }
});
```

We need to add 2 packages for this code to work :

```
meteor add reactive-var
meteor add aldeed:template-extension
```

Comment: This is great! The only thing is that I want to update it on every webpage that views it, I'm not sure sessions is what I'm after?

Comment: Then you should put it in a Meteor collection.